# Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.ClassCastException in android version of phonegap project on testdroid

Tags: android, cordova, testdroid

First of all I am sorry if the question is silly as i am new to phonegap, i tried few answers here but they dont match my query. 
I have been working on a phonegap project, currently there is no splash screen plugin, i have the design in www folder which has index.html page which i use as a splashs screen, the app working fine in device, but when i test the apk in [testdroid](https://cloud.testdroid.com) it gives the following error.

> 'Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.ClassCastException''.
>   Check device logcat for details

i can see my index.html page in screenshot in the test provide by testdroid, please suggest me something to remove this error.

Please find the logs below.

```
--------- beginning of crash
08-19 09:44:37.682  4326  4326 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-19 09:44:37.682  4326  4326 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.gedtests, PID: 4326
08-19 09:44:37.682  4326  4326 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.robotium.solo.RobotiumWebClient cannot be cast to org.apache.cordova.engine.SystemWebChromeClient
08-19 09:44:37.682  4326  4326 E AndroidRuntime:    at org.apache.cordova.engine.SystemWebView.setWebChromeClient(SystemWebView.java:76)
08-19 09:44:37.682  4326  4326 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.robotium.solo.RobotiumWebClient$1.run(RobotiumWebClient.java:59)
08-19 09:44:37.682  4326  4326 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Instrumentation$SyncRunnable.run(Instrumentation.java:1855)
08-19 09:44:37.682  4326  4326 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
08-19 09:44:37.682  4326  4326 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-19 09:44:37.682  4326  4326 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
08-19 09:44:37.682  4326  4326 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5240)
08-19 09:44:37.682  4326  4326 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
08-19 09:44:37.682  4326  4326 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
08-19 09:44:37.682  4326  4326 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
08-19 09:44:37.682  4326  4326 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
08-19 09:44:37.690   634   666 W ActivityManager: Error in app com.gedtests running instrumentation ComponentInfo{testdroid.appcrawler.testcrawler/testdroid.appcrawler.testcrawler.AppCrawlerRunner}:
08-19 09:44:37.690   634   666 W ActivityManager:   java.lang.ClassCastException
08-19 09:44:37.691   634   666 W ActivityManager:   java.lang.ClassCastException: com.robotium.solo.RobotiumWebClient cannot be cast to org.apache.cordova.engine.SystemWebChromeClient
08-19 09:44:37.699  4308  4308 D AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
08-19 09:44:37.965   634   666 I ActivityManager: Force stopping com.gedtests appid=11960 user=0: finished inst
08-19 09:44:37.965   634   666 I ActivityManager: Killing 4326:com.gedtests/u0a1960 (adj 0): stop com.gedtests
```

Comment: Reobotium does not support cordova based apps.